# form with ajax - message form php without refresh page

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to send form using an ajax call without refreshing the page

Html

```
<form id="form">
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio1">
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio1">

<input type="checkbox" name="box" value="box1">
<input type="checkbox" name="box" value="box2">

<input type="text" name="text" value="box2">

<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="embtn btn-1" value="Send" onclick="submitform()">

</form>
```

This is JS code

```
function submitform(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url : 'assets/php/brief-wiz.php', 
        type: 'post', 
        data: $('form').serialize() 
    }).done(function(html) {
        $( ".form-message" ).append( html );
    });
};
```

PHP

```
<?php

$errors = [];

if (empty($_POST["radio"])) {
    $errors[] = "Complete radio ";
} else { 
    $radio = implode($_POST['radio']);
}

if (empty($_POST["box"])) {
    $errors[] = "Complete box ";
} else { 
    $box = implode($_POST['box']);
}

$text = ($_POST['text']);   

$body = "";

$body .=  "<div><b>1:</b> " . $profil . "</div>";
$body .=  "<div><b>2:</b> " . $box . $text . "</div>";

$to       = 'mymail@com.pl';
$subject  = 'Contact;
$message  =  $body;

$headers = "From: webmaster@example.com" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: " . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";

$success = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);


echo $success ? "Mail sended" : "Error";


?>
```

Now my page is reloading without messgaes.

Without this code:

```
(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Messages shows for one second, but the page is reloading.
How can I load the messages using PHP without refreshing the page.

Comment: could you please give more information like your html ? i did not get what is the main problem but note that any button element inside the form will do the submit. so you have to prevent it to submit the form and do it with your ajax call

Comment: “It doesn’t work” is not a proper problem description. Please go read [ask] and [mcve], and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Check your console, there is some error.

Answer (score 2):

Use Javascript Event :

**HTML**

```html
<form id="form" action="assets/php/brief-wiz.php">
    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio1">
    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio1">

    <input type="checkbox" name="box" value="box1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="box" value="box2">

    <input type="text" name="text" value="box2">

    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="embtn btn-1" value="Send">
</form>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$('form').on('submit',function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var form = event.currentTarget;
  $.ajax(
    {
        url : $(form).attr('action'), 
        type: 'post', 
        data: $(form).serialize() 
    }
  ).done(
    function(html) {
        $( ".form-message" ).append( html );
    }
  );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your submit input type to a button.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the type of your button is submit !
I am suggesting you to use this instead :

```
<button id="submit" class="embtn btn-1" onclick="submitform()">Send</button>
```